# How to populate properties of an empty object using two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, while-loop

I have two arrays, I am trying to populate key-value pairs(properties) of an empty object using elements of these arrays. the code below is not working. Please tell me what is wrong here, also, is there a better way of doing this?

```
  let arr13 = ["name", "age", "hobby", "habit", "vocation"];
  let arr14 = ["superhero", 40, "swimming", "drinking", "programming"];

  let mapped = {};
  let j = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr13.length; i++) {
    while (j < arr14.length) {
      let key = arr13[i];
      mapped.key = arr14[j];
      j++;
      break;
    }
  }

  console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: Please, specify what is expected output.

Comment: expected output is: {name:"superhero", age:40, hobby:"swimming", habit:"drinking", vocation:"programming"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
let arr13 = ["name", "age", "hobby", "habit", "vocation"];
let arr14 = ["superhero", 40, "swimming", "drinking", "programming"];

let mapped = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr13.length; i++) {
    mapped[arr13[i]] = arr14[i];
}
console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 1):

Map the 1st array, and take the item with the same index from the 2nd array to create an array of `[kay, value]` pairs. Convert to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const zipObject = (arr1, arr2) =>
  Object.fromEntries(arr1.map((a, i) => [a, arr2[i]]));

const arr13 = ["name", "age", "hobby", "habit", "vocation"];
const arr14 = ["superhero", 40, "swimming", "drinking", "programming"];

const result = zipObject(arr13, arr14);

console.log(result);
```

What's wrong with your code - use the same index to take the relevant key and value from both arrays:

```js
let arr13 = ["name", "age", "hobby", "habit", "vocation"];
let arr14 = ["superhero", 40, "swimming", "drinking", "programming"];

let mapped = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr13.length; i++) {
  mapped[arr13[i]] = arr14[i];
}

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: Hey Ori, I'm new to stackoverflow, how can I make my code examples being able to be runnable as yours?

Comment: Edit your answer, and click the snippet button - `<>`, and copy/paste your code into right places. I've changed your 1st solution to a snippet, so you'll have an example.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's see what's wrong with your code:

When you do this `mapped.key = arr14[j]` you are actually adding the content of arr14[j] to a key called "key" in your mapped object.

To fix it you can change your code to:

```js
let arr13 = ["name", "age", "hobby", "habit", "vocation"];
let arr14 = ["superhero", 40, "swimming", "drinking", "programming"];

let mapped = {};
let j = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr13.length; i++) {
    while (j < arr14.length) {
      let key = arr13[i];
      mapped[key] = arr14[j];
      j++;
      break;
    }
}
console.log(mapped);
```

Because when you do `object[variable]` you are actually adding to the object a key with the name that the variable contains.

Also we can make some quick improvements in this code changing it to:

```js
const arr13 = ["name", "age", "hobby", "habit", "vocation"];
const arr14 = ["superhero", 40, "swimming", "drinking", "programming"];

const mapped = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr13.length; i++) {
      const key = arr13[i];
      mapped[key] = arr14[i];
}
console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: It works, thanx very much. by the way, aren't we supposed to put the var inside square brackets wrapped in quotes?

Comment: Let me explain this using two examples:

First:
````
const keyName = "age";
object[keyName] = 32;
````
when you do this is the same of doing object["age"] = 32; because keyName = "age""

if you do: 

```` 
const keyName = "age";
object["keyName"] = 32;
````

your object will be {"keyname" 32} instead of {"age": 32}

Answer (score 0):

here is an example using Reduce

```
let arr13 = ["name", "age", "hobby", "habit", "vocation"];
let arr14 = ["superhero", 40, "swimming", "drinking", "programming"];

const result = arr13.reduce((a, value, index) => {
    a[value] = arr14[index];
    return a
}, {});

console.log(result)
// {"name": "superhero","age": 40,"hobby": "swimming","habit": "drinking","vocation": "programming"}
```

Comment: This does something but not what I was looking for. the objective is to have an object but not an array, containing key-value pairs like a regular array would do (not a collection of dict or objects. thanx anyway. your solution will be useful in some other scenario. got two working solutions from other members.

Comment: @sb16 i made an update to the method, check now it returns ```Objet {key : value}```